# get for many to many relations

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

```
Tag:
  columns:
    name:              
      type: string(100)

TagNews:
  columns:
    tag_id:  
      type: integer
      primary: true
    news_id:   
      type: integer
      primary: true 
  relations:
    Tag:     { onDelete: CASCADE, local: tag_id, foreign: id }
    News:      { onDelete: CASCADE, local: news_id, foreign: id }

News:
  columns:
    tag_id:        
      type: integer
    name:               
      type: string(100)
  relations:
    Tag:
      class: Tag
      refClass: TagNews
      local: news_id
      foreign: tag_id
      foreignAlias: TagNews


TAG:
| id | name |
| 1  | tag1 |
| 2  | tag2 |
| 3  | tag3 |


TagNews:
| id_tag | tag_news |
| 1      |  1       |
| 2      |  1       |
| 2      |  2       |
| 3      |  2       |
| 3      |  3       |
| 1      |  3       |

News:

| id  | name  |
| 1   | news1 |
| 2   | news2 |
| 3   | news3 |
| 4   | news4 |
| 5   | news5 |
```

how can i get all news for tag1 etc?

for example **site.com/tag/tag1** ?
what i must write in action.class and template? i use Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tag = TagTable::getInstance()->find(1);
$news = $tag->getNews();
```

should work.. otherwise you'll have to define the relation to news in the tag (same as tag in news)